# Unable to read in the all the html of a webpage using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to pull in form-10k from SEC using Beautifulsoup. Unfortunately, the following codes are not displaying all of the html. It is printing starting from somewhere in the middle of the html. However, it works fine when applied for several other web pages I tried. Any help will be much appreciated. I'm very new to python coding and I'm hoping to learn more as it is starting to grow on me :)

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/920148/000092014820000011/lh10-k2019.htm"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify().encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Cannot replicate, running your code prints the whole page.

Comment: It was not printing the whole html due to insufficient space in my pycharm console. After increasing the buffer size, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is probably happening is that there is not enough space in your terminal so what you see is only part of it, but in fact the whole page is there. I'm guessing the pages that worked are much shorter.

Comment: Thanks for commenting... Is there a way to increase the space so I can see the entire html? I applied regular expression to the result, but it produced an empty list. That is when I printed to see the html and noticed it was printing from way below the section I want to operate on.

Comment: depends on what terminal you're using... if its the windows command prompt you can increase buffer size - see here: https://www.top-password.com/blog/change-screen-buffer-size-in-windows-command-prompt/

Comment: It was a space issue indeed. After increasing the console buffer size sufficiently, it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!